# How to intentionally lock a workflow task in Infopath for SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, locking, workflow, task, infopath

I wish to intentionally lock a workflow task in SharePoint 2010 for an infopath form.

I have a solution to solve a lock in place. I just want to be able to intentionally set a lock so I can test my unlocking solution.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're talking about "The file is locked for exclusive use by...", the easiest way is to have another user open the file. I'm not aware of how this type of lock can affect workflow-created tasks, since they're lists and not libraries. Maybe have them open it for editing? You could also invoke the [SPFile.Lock()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.lock.aspx) method. [Here is an unlocking application whose code you might be able to modify to suit your needs.](https://spunlockfiles.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I couldn't exactly write an application to intentionally lock it. I had to reproduce them in the wild. So I simply wrote a side application to use up all the system resources (networking, processor, memory, etc.) to slow it to a crawl to throw off the synchronization between the SharePoint databases. Thus throwing a lock on the workflow. Worked like a charm. Your suggestions were all awesome though. Just didn't fit in this situation.